# Why doesn't Google Cloud Free Trial start after properly filling the form?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, g-suite, credentials

I signed up for the free tier of Google Cloud. I completed the entire process (phone verification, card details, address, cardholder name etc.) I chose account type as *business* instead of *individual*, because I want multiple accounts to be able to access the platform. It asks for a business name which I entered. I didn't give tax details though, because they were optional. Then I pressed the "Unlock My Free Trial" button after which it asks for CVV, which I entered. Even a transaction of a nominal amount was made from my account to validate it. But after this, it just goes back to the previous page (the form at the end of which was the "Unlock My Trial Button"), and nothing happens. My trial isn't started. Every time I click on the button and give my CVV, a nominal transaction occurs, but it doesn't unlock.

Am I supposed to give my tax details? Why could this be happening?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

- Tax details are not required.
- Prepaid cards are not accepted.
- Go to your Google Payments account and look for problems. https://pay.google.com/
- Most likely your credit card is not validating your identity OR does not accept recurring payments.
- Contact your credit card issuer/bank and ask them to review/approve the Google payments. Not all cards will. In that case, use a different credit/debit card.

Additional links that might help you:

- [Indian debit or credit card not accepted](https://support.google.com/a/answer/3401127?hl=en) Applies to Google Cloud also.
- [Supported payment methods](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/payment-methods?visit_id=637552341726690202-4046999228&rd=1#supported_payment_methods)